# How to read in CSV file that has tab row delimiters and pipe '|' column delimiters?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read in a CSV file into R that has row and column delimiters:

A vertical bar or pipe | is the row delimiter.
Tab is the column delimiter.

Example dataset:

```
Column A      Column B      Column C|Red            Shorts            10|Blue            Shirt             7|Yellow          Skirt            15
```

I'm not sure how to specify both of these in the read.csv function as there is on the option for field separator characters with 'sep'.

Comment: With your current attempts do you get an error or just a `|` in your first column of data?

Comment: I assume by "row delimiter" you mean pipe instead of newline? So your example data should be on one line?

Comment: I think there's a way with either some clever string replacement or some `purrr` functions. But it's unclear what format you're *actually* trying to read. You say this is tab-delimited, but in your example it's just whitespace that isn't necessarily tabs. Do you have a version with actual tabs?

Comment: Sorry, am new on here and didn't know how to format the code. I ended up finding a solution through Python and then R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not seem possible in R so I ended up reading the data into Python, replacing the pipe delimiter with new line and then was able to then read the data in R as it now only contained one delimiter.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if the `.csv` is `|` seperated. It should look like below. For example; imagine there's a file called `foo.csv` on with content,

```
Column A|Column B|Column C
|Red|Shorts|10
```

And the R code to read it would be;

```
foo <- read.csv('<path to>/foo.csv', sep = "|")
head(foo)
```

If the delimiter is a tab, you have to do;

```
foo <- read.csv('<path to>/foo.csv', sep = "\t")
```

But not both.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP has 2 delimiters, not just `|`

Comment: Question was later updated. There’s no way you could read with two delimiters.

Comment: The data did have two delimiters

Comment: Ok, what I meant was there’s no straightforward function to read a csv that has two delimiters afaik.